# Modern OpenGL Sprite Drawing - Not Rendering

Tags: opengl, sprites, lwjgl

I'm trying to render sprites based of [this](http://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/2D-Game/Rendering-Sprites) tutorial, in LWJGL.

Here's what I have so far, with descriptions of what class I use:

`Transformable2D` is a class that holds transform matrices meant for 2D rendering, and `Drawable` is just an interface that has a `draw()` function.

`Texture` is a container for loading and creating Textures, and its `bind` function just sets the active  texture to it's ID and binds itself to the passed unit parameter.

`SpriteTechnique` is a container for a shader program, and I will paste the shaders here too, although they are the same as from the tutorial.

I make the shader and vao static, because every Sprite uses the same vao and shader.

Finally, I pass a `View` to the `draw()` function, which holds the necessary info to make an orthogonal matrix based off the transforms of the object. This matrix is correct, as I also use it for text rendering, where it works as expected.

All of  the classes described above work completely; I am 100% sure the problem is not within the backing classes. Here are the GL settings I set in my backend, too:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

So, onto the actual class:

```
public class Sprite extends Transformable2D implements Drawable {

    private Texture texture;

    private Vector3f color;

    private static SpriteTechnique tech = new SpriteTechnique();

    private static boolean isRendererInitialized;

    private static int vao;

    public Sprite(Texture texture) {
        this.texture = texture;
        color = new Vector3f();
    }

    public static boolean initRenderer() {
        if (isRendererInitialized) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!tech.init()) {
            return false;
        }

        float[] vertices = {
            // Pos      // Tex
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
        };
        FloatBuffer vertexBuf = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        vertexBuf.put(vertices);
        vertexBuf.flip();

        vao = glGenVertexArrays();

        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        int vbo = glGenBuffers();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 16, 0);

        //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        //glBindVertexArray(0);

        isRendererInitialized = true;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(View v, RenderStates states) {
        if (!isRendererInitialized) {
            System.err.println("Sprite renderer must be initialized before drawing sprites!");
            return;
        }

        tech.enable();

        tech.setTextureUnit(COLOR_TEXTURE_UNIT_INDEX);
        tech.setColor(color);
        tech.setProjection(getOrthoTrans(v).getMatrix());

        texture.bind(COLOR_TEXTURE_UNIT);

        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        //glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

Here are my shaders:

Sprite.vs:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex; // <vec2 position, vec2 texCoords>

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 gProjection;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
    gl_Position = gProjection * vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Sprite.fs:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D gSpriteTexture;
uniform vec3 gSpriteColor;

void main()
{    
    color = vec4(gSpriteColor, 1.0) * texture(gSpriteTexture, TexCoords);
}
```

When I try to render a Sprite, however, nothing appears on the screen. Not even a black quad. I've tried to scale the quad, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're drawing clockwise, thats the backface. Disable backface-culling and try again.

Comment: @tkausl Nothing is rendering still, but I updated my code with the current state of it.

Comment: Are you sure your ortho-matrix is correct? Any glError's?

Comment: @tkausl I am sure, there are no glErrors, I've checked. I use the same matrix for my text rendering, which works fine. If you would like, I can add to the OP what my matrix is when I don't apply any transforms on it.

Comment: @tkausl I set the front face to clockwise in my backend system, anyway. So disabling backface culling shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Bind your vao before GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. Also don't unbind buffers. All bindings are kept in vao.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Added your changes, see edited code. Still nothing rendering... hm

Comment: @Tetramputechture check if any OpenGL functions are returning any errors using glGetError()

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Did that in many places, no errors at all.